# What's the differents between selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition: and scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm new to Obj-C. When I selected a cell with `selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` wouldn't be called. So I call them in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, the final effect is the same.

What's the difference between them?

Comment: Did you read the doc? For `selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`, it says "This method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called.".

Comment: Saw it.So how could I use it correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first method you mentioned (`selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`) actually selects the item at the provided indexPath. Optionally, it can also scroll to it.

The second method you mentioned (`scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:`) only scrolls the collection view until the specified item is visible. It doesn't select it.

In your case, if I understand correctly, you're describing a scenario in which an item has already been selected (`didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`), so you just need to call the second method if you want to make sure that the item is visible (it doesn't need to be selected again). Or, you can replace the original method (`selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`) with `selectItemAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:` to select the cell (but, notice that according to the spec, as mentioned in the comments to your original question, "this method does not cause any selection-related delegate methods to be called", so you won't receive the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:` call.